# Chat application with Swift + Parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform, chat

have anyone an idea how i can create a iOS chat app with Swift and use Parse as backEnd? I found this: https://layer.com but it is written in objective-C. There is a swift version too, but it is full of issues and I don't know how to solve them.

Comment: I think challenge you are going to face is long polling.  Parse does have cloud function, see if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below Reference links may help you:

An Example iOS Chat Application with Parse, written in Swift

https://github.com/huyouare/SwiftParseChat